# What is the word for 'while eating' or 'during a meal'?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Is there a word for, as mentioned above, 'while eating' or 'during a meal'? If the word was say, `rtrt` then we could go like: rtrt burping is a common phenomenon.

I remember reading such a word (and it started with 'p' probably), but can't recall it.

Thanks!

Comment: Start with 'prandial'?

Comment: Hi Chahat, 1) does that really match what you were expecting? 2) did you follow up with a thesaurus 3) that word is pretty ... rare and would sound strange no matter what. Do you have a sentence in which this sought after word would occur?

Comment: @Mitch, thanks for the follow-up. 1) yes, doesn't it?  2) somehow i couldn't find the word in a thesaurus but its dictionary meaning was what i expected  3) yes, i thought so. Wanted to know how you guys know about it and if you use it. I had read the word in a scientific paper as `post-prandial glucose level` i guess. But yes, doesn't seem like a word for daily conversations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"prandial"** is the word you are looking for.

- Just mentioned in a comment by Mitch, it's the word I use in my everyday practice. In a doctor's office some patients complain of **post-prandial fullness**. Some who are diabetic have been on **prandial** Insulin for a long time. Others have been on a **prandial** glucose regulator such as Metformin.

> [**prandial**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prandial) (adj) "of or relating to a meal."

It's not much used by the layman, though.

Comment: It was much used in the advertising world of 70's & 80's, especially in the UK's TV commercials before Christmas for festive post-prandial liqueurs, Ports & chocolates (Grand Marnier, Cointreau and Sanderman & Cockburns's Port) and, most memorably, After Eight Mints. My post-prandial tipple of choice at Christmas was more likely to be Alka-Seltzer!